# MYSQL - UPDATE multipul enties in a column

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I need to update multipul feilds in a single column based on a search in a different column.

This is what I have so far which is not even close I know :(

```
SELECT *  FROM `news` WHERE `email` = 'test@hotmail.com', 'cyberc@gmail.com', 'trevor@live.com'
```

I need to search for all reqired emails and update the fleild in column called `profile_4`

Any advise is very much appreciated.

C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `IN` operator:

```
SELECT *  FROM `news`
WHERE `email` IN ('test@hotmail.com', 'cyberc@gmail.com', 'trevor@live.com');
```

For update use:

```
UPDATE `news` SET `profile_4`=%your_value_here% 
WHERE `email` IN ('test@hotmail.com', 'cyberc@gmail.com', 'trevor@live.com');
```